# Demonstration that electric current at equilibrium is zero in crystals

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electric-current, equilibrium, quantum-transport

As it is well known, electrons at equilibrium (no external field) do not conduct electric current, i.e.

$\int_{BZ} dk\,v_{k}\,f(\epsilon_k)=0$

where $f(\epsilon_k)$ is the Fermi-Dirac distribution

$f(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{e^{\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}+1}$

$v_k$ is the velocity

$v_k=\frac{\partial \epsilon_k}{\partial k}$

and $BZ$ is the Brillouin zone.

Is it possible to demonstrate that just using the explicit expression 
of the Fermi-Dirac distribution and the fact that we are considering functions periodic on the reciprocal lattice? I mean, is it possible to say that the integral is zero just from the general properties of the quantities involved? (for example, in the free-electron case it comes from the fact that it is the integral of an odd function in $k$).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't valence electrons conduct electricity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/762701/why-cant-valence-electrons-conduct-electricity) Also [Filled Band cannot generate current](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/692670/247642) In a nutshell - for every electron moving to the right there is another one, going to the left, so their currents cancel each other.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I am trying to answer this question(partially) from symmetry considerations.

If the system has the time reversal or inversion symmetry, then $\varepsilon_{-k}=\varepsilon_{k}$. From this $v(-k)=-v(k)$, and $f(\varepsilon_{-k})=f(\varepsilon_k)$. Since for any point $k$ in the BZ, we can always find its counterpart $-k$, therefore the integration over the entire BZ is zero.

I don't know how to argue if the the system breaks both inversion and time-reversal symmetry.

Comment: Is it even true if there is no time-reversal symmetry?

Comment: @fqq I am not sure, what is the flaw of above argument if there is only inversion symmetry?

Comment: The question seems very old and I am not sure why it popped back up in my list. At any rate, I don't think that answers the question. The answer actually made no assumption about equilibrium. Instead, the implicit assumption that was made is that all k states are occupied so that they cancel out by symmetry. What this shows is that a fully occcupied band cannot carry current (equilibrium or not). This is a valid point but pretty different from what was asked I think

Comment: A 2D/1D strip with in plane time-reversal-breaking magnetic field and hall voltage, can have hall current. Not totally sure if this is a counter example that shows time reversal or inversion symmetry is necessary. The hall voltage might have some weird boundary condition.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the periodicity of the band energy $\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}}=\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{G}}$. Define
$$
F(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{\beta}\log\left(\frac{1+\mathrm{e}^{-\beta(\epsilon-\mu)}}{\beta}\right)
$$
to be the antiderivative of $f(\epsilon)$, i.e. $F'(\epsilon)=f(\epsilon)$. Then in one dimension
$$
J = \int_{\text{BZ}} \frac{\mathrm{d}k}{2\pi}\,v(k)f(\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}}) = \int \frac{\mathrm{d}k}{2\pi}\,\frac{\partial\epsilon(k)}{\partial k_i}F'(\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}}) = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}k}{2\pi}\,\frac{\partial F(\epsilon_{\mathbf{k}})}{\partial k_i}=F(\epsilon_{\pi})-F(\epsilon_{-\pi})=0
$$
as $\epsilon_{k=\pi}=\epsilon_{k=-\pi}$. This argument extends to higher dimensions too.

Answer (score 0):

> As it is well known, electrons at equilibrium (no external field) do
> not conduct electric current

This phrase may be justified by the subsequent context, but, taken separately, it sounds strange, as there are superconductors.