# Why can't valence electrons conduct electricity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

The simplified $E-k$ diagram obtained from Kronnig-Penney model looks like that:
[image]

The bottom curve corresponds to the so-called valence electrons, and the upper curve - to conduction electrons.

But these are simply *the allowed states*. Kronnig-Penney model doesn't (at least, immediately) tell us that only the bottom states are for the electrons that can move freely and cause electricity to flow.

Is the fact that the bottom electrons are bound to nuclei and the upper electrons are free to move just an assumption? Or does this fact have theoretical derivation (if so, I would like to see one)?

Comment: Both can move, but conduction electrons cany move way easier. "It is just that symmetric filling cancel out, and full bands are symmetric" - I didn't understand this. I ask questions because I want to understand the physics. And "of this type" - if you refer to my question about why $E_C$ corresponds to the electrostatic potential, - because this is not eplained by any book, it is just stated. And I still do not understand that as well

Comment: It's not an assumption. It's a fact: we observe that insulating materials exist. Band theory is a *model* that captures this fundamental observation.

Comment: @JohnDoty my question is basically "how does it follow from this model that only the electrons with energies above the band gap are the ones responsible for the conduction of electricity?"

Comment: In a full band, for every electron with a $k$ in one direction, there is another electron with $k$ in the other direction, so there is no net current flow. In an unfilled band that is not true. Metals have ~1/2 filled bands (lots of handwaving away solid state physics). Semiconductor have a few electrons in the conduction band and a few holes in the valence band, and those conduct current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be clear, valence band electrons (or lack thereof, i.e. holes) can and do carry current, you might find [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/755033/171547) useful. A band that is completely filled doesn't carry current. Here is a proof, following Ashcroft & Mermin. We start by proving an integral identity. Suppose that $f(\mathbf r)$ is a periodic function with the periodicity of a [Bravais lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice), meaning in 3D,
$$f(\mathbf r + n_1 \mathbf a_1 + n_2 \mathbf a_2 + n_3 \mathbf a_3) = f(\mathbf r)$$
where $\mathbf a_j$ are the primitive vectors spanning the lattice, and $n_j$ are arbitrary integers. Define
$$I(\mathbf r')=\int\limits_Cf(\mathbf r+\mathbf r')\ d\mathbf r,$$
a volume integral over primitive cell $C$. This integral is just $\int\limits_{C'}f(\mathbf r)\ d\mathbf r$ where $C'$ is $C$ shifted by $\mathbf r'$, which is another primitive cell. Due to the periodicity of $f$, its integral over any primitive cell is the same, meaning $I(\mathbf r')$ is independent of $\mathbf r'$:
$$\mathbf \nabla'I(\mathbf r')=\int\limits_C\mathbf \nabla'f(\mathbf r+\mathbf r')\ d\mathbf r=\int\limits_C\mathbf \nabla f(\mathbf r+\mathbf r')\ d\mathbf r = 0$$
Plugging in $\mathbf r'=0$,
$$\int\limits_C\mathbf \nabla f(\mathbf r)\ d\mathbf r = 0.$$
This is the result we were looking for: a Green's theorem for periodic functions. It says that the integral of the gradient of a periodic function over a primitive cell is zero.

Now, the current density contribution of an energy band is

$$\mathbf J =\int\limits_B\frac{d\mathbf k}{4\pi^3}(-q)g(\mathbf k)\mathbf v(\mathbf k).$$
Here, $B$ is the first Brillouin zone, $g(\mathbf k)$ is the probability of occupancy of the state with wave vector $\mathbf k$, and $\mathbf v(\mathbf k)=\frac 1 \hbar\mathbf \nabla_{\mathbf k} E(\mathbf k)$ is the group velocity where $E (\mathbf k)$ is the energy of the state with wave vector $\mathbf k$. For a completely filled band, $g(\mathbf k)=1$, so
$$\mathbf J =\frac{-q}{4\pi^3\hbar}\int\limits_Bd\mathbf k\nabla_{\mathbf k} E(\mathbf k).$$
Since $E(\mathbf k)$ is a periodic function with the periodicity of the reciprocal lattice, and the first Brillouin zone is a Wigner-Seitz primitive cell, the integral identity we proved above applies, and the current density is zero.

Comment: Proofs are mathematics, not physics, only as good as their axioms. But nature doesn't give us axioms, it gives us phenomena. So this is a *rationalization* of the physics. It's a good, effective one, but it doesn't prove anything physical. Only experiments can do that.

Comment: @JohnDoty I'm certainly open to suggestions if you have a more appropriate word for arguments/statements used to arrive at a certain proposition/result, starting with a set of axioms or established consequences thereof. I don't know if we can show that filled bands carry no net current purely experimentally with no regard to models/axioms, considering "bands" are part of the model we use to describe conduction in solids.

Comment: The word I used was "rationalization".

Comment: With all due respect, I don't think "rationalization" has the meaning I'm looking for, especially given the concern I expressed above regarding whether this statement even can be meaningfully "proved" strictly experimentally. I do think that the word "proof" is acceptable here, with the understanding that we are working in the framework of a model, the axioms and consequences of which only relate to reality to the extent their predictions agree with experiment.

Comment: The trouble with "proof" is that it causes people to believe that the model itself is true. But models are never truth. Experimentally, we can prove things in the "proving ground" sense: we actually test our hypotheses. Can't do that on a whiteboard.

Comment: @JohnDoty Well, I was basically asking about a proof that this is _implied by Kronig-Penney model_

Answer (score 2):

Usually bands are symmetric, i.e., for any state with quasimomentum $\mathbf{k}$, we have a state with quasimomentum $-\mathbf{k}$. Electrons occupying these states have velocities
$$
v(\mathbf{k})=\frac{1}{\hbar}\nabla_\mathbf{k}E(\mathbf{k})
$$
and $$-v(\mathbf{k}).$$ Thus, the contribution of every electron to current is cancelled out by the electron with the opposite momentum.

When applying electric field, we shift the chemical potentials for electrons moving in the directions along and against the field, that is the states in conduction band with positive momenta have higher/lower occupancy than the states with negative momenta. This is not the case with in the valence band, where all the states are already occupied and nothing changes... unless the field is so strong that it transfers some electrons to the conduction band (Zener tunneling.)

See also [Filled band cannot generate current](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/692670/247642)